# How do I set seconds to 00 when increasing or decreasing my countdown timer?

Tags: swift, nstimer

Im using NSTimer to build a countdown timer and I use two buttons to increase and decrease the time. I want to be able to set the countdown timer seconds to 00 when increasing or decreasing the time. So for example lets say the timer is at 10:42 and I press the decrease button once it should go to 10:00 instead of 9:42. How would I be able to do that? Here is the code Im using currently to increase and decrease the time:

```
var timeCount:TimeInterval = 1800 //seconds



func startTimer() {
    focusTimer.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 1.5)
    focusTimer.fontName = "Helvetica"
    focusTimer.text = "30 00"
    focusTimer.fontColor = UIColor.white
    focusTimer.fontSize = 50
    focusTimer.zPosition = 79
    focusTimer.name = "focustimer"
    addChild(focusTimer)
}

func timeStringForScore3(_ time:TimeInterval) -> String {
    let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(time) % 60
    return String(format:"%02i %02i", minutes, seconds)
}

func updateStopWatch3() {
    self.timeCount -= 1
    focusTimer.text = timeStringForScore3(timeCount)
}



@discardableResult
func nextMinute(after seconds: TimeInterval) -> TimeInterval {
    return (seconds/60 + 1).rounded(.down) * 60
}

@discardableResult
func previousMinute(before seconds: TimeInterval) -> TimeInterval {
    return (seconds/60 - 1).rounded(.up) * 60
}



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


for touch in touches {



if node.name == "increase" {
nextMinute(after: timeCount)
focusTimer.text = timeStringForScore3(timeCount)
}


if node.name == "decrease" {
previousMinute(before: timeCount)
focusTimer.text = timeStringForScore3(timeCount)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the value to the next full minute you can proceed as follows:

- Divide by 60 to convert the seconds to minutes, then add one.
- Round down to the next integer to get the full minute,
  then multiply by 60 again to convert the value to seconds.

Decreasing works accordingly:

```
func nextMinute(after seconds: TimeInterval) -> TimeInterval {
    return (seconds/60 + 1).rounded(.down) * 60
}

func previousMinute(before seconds: TimeInterval) -> TimeInterval {
    return (seconds/60 - 1).rounded(.up) * 60
}
```

Test cases:

```
nextMinute(after: 1800.0) // 1860
nextMinute(after: 1800.1) // 1860
nextMinute(after: 1799.9) // 1800
nextMinute(after: 0.0)    // 60
nextMinute(after: -15.0)  // 0
nextMinute(after: -60.0)  // 0
nextMinute(after: -61.0)  // -60

previousMinute(before: 1800.0) // 1740
previousMinute(before: 1800.1) // 1800
previousMinute(before: 1799.9) // 1740
previousMinute(before: 0.0)    // -60
previousMinute(before: -15.0)  // -60
previousMinute(before: -60.0)  // -120
previousMinute(before: -61.0)  // -120
```

Comment: When I press the decrease button it goes down by 1 sec and when I press the increase button it goes up a full 60 seconds and the seconds doesnt set to 00.

Comment: BTW my timeCount variable is set to 1800 seconds.

Comment: @coding22 My solution assumes that timeCount is an Int.

Comment: Oh my bad I should have put that in the op. Would you know how to do it if its set to a specific value like 1800?

Comment: Thanks for the help but Im having a problem. When I press either the increase or decrease button it doesnt increase or decrease the time. I updated the code in the op. Can you check if Im calling it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: You should not discard the return value, but assign it to the variable: `timeCount = previousMinute(before: timeCount)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if node.name == "increase" {

        timeCount = timeCount + (60 - (timeCount % 60))
        focusTimer.text = timeStringForScore3(timeCount)
  }


if node.name == "decrease" {
        timeCount = timeCount - (timeCount % 60)
        focusTimer.text = timeStringForScore3(timeCount)
}
```

Comment: When I increase the time using your code it increases it by 30 seconds and doesn't set the seconds to 00. So when its at 30:28 it goes to 30:58. And when I decrease the time it decreases by 31 seconds.